# Tutorial Turtlebot 3dsensor not working with Kinect

Tags: ros, kinect, turtlebot, tutorial, freenect

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,

I am working on Ubuntu 14.04 with ROS Indigo

I was following the turtlebot tutorials, and found that the

roslaunch turtlebot_bringup 3dsensor.launch

instruction in the 3d visualisation tutorial didn't recognize the kinect, while

roslaunch freenect_launch freenect.launch

did.
Then i went on the SLAM tutorial but had the same problem because it use the 3dsensor.launch file.
I had to remove the

agr name="3d_sensor" default="$( env TURTLEBOT_3D_SENSOR)"

line of the 3dsensor.launch and manually select the kinect.launch file in the

include file="$(find turtlebot_bringup)/launch/includes/3dsensor/$(arg 3dsensor ).launch.xml

Is that a problem that happened to others, and actually need a modification of the file to work, or is it that i did something wrong ?

EDIT :
After following jihoonl's advice, i deleted ROS and re installed it from scratch, and this time this part worked fine. But i had another problem when loading the map i created during "SLAM Map Building with TurtleBot"'s tutorial :
The amdl_demo.launch was loading a map whose path was fixed ( find turtlebot_navigation`/maps/willow-2010-02-18-0.10.yaml )and not dependent on the ROS environment variable we were asked to choose. Did i once again forgot some part of the tutorials ?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/205942/tutorial-turtlebot-3dsensor-not-working-with-kinect/) by [Swan Baigne](https://answers.ros.org/users/21982/swan-baigne/) on ROS Answers with karma: 47 on 2015-03-26

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

This link will help you.

http://wiki.ros.org/turtlebot/Tutorials/indigo/Kinect%20Setup

---

Originally posted by [jihoonl](https://answers.ros.org/users/830/jihoonl/) with karma: 634 on 2015-03-29

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Swan Baigne](https://answers.ros.org/users/21982/swan-baigne/) on 2015-03-30**:
Thanks for your answers, i already did this but it seems it didn't register in my source.bash